# TypeError: Consumer key must be string or bytes, not NoneType when authentication

Tags: python, tweepy

Planning to use variables to authorize tweepy with Twitter's API, but it shows the following:
`TypeError: Consumer key must be string or bytes, not NoneType when authentication`

Code below:

```py
import tweepy
import os

consumera = os.environ.get('TWICK')
consumerb = os.environ.get('TWICS')
accessa = os.environ.get('TWIAT')
accessb = os.environ.get('TWIATS')

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumera, consumerb)
auth.set_access_token(accessa, accessb)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

status = api.update_status(status="Test tweet.")
```

I've tried using other authentication methods, such as:

```py
consumera = os.environ.get('TWICK')
consumerb = os.environ.get('TWICS')
accessa = os.environ.get('TWIAT')
accessb = os.environ.get('TWIATS')

client = tweepy.Client(consumer_key=consumera,
                       consumer_secret=consumerb,
                       access_token=accessa,
                       access_token_secret=accessb
                       )
```

Any fix?

Additional info: I was planning to run it through GitHub actions but without exposing the keys in the source code - and I put all the keys as secrets, so it requires environmental access. Tested on Ubuntu (both local and under GitHub Actions), but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a typo problem? NoneType is caused because one of the methods is receiving None, which is returned by **get()** if the environment variable does not exist.

Check if your environment variables' names are correct.

If your problem persists please indicate in which line the error occurs.

Comment: Checked, and all variables are correct. But if using variables such as ``consumera = os.environ['TWICK']``, it will return ``KeyError: 'TWICK'``. Also, I verified all the variables that those are correct. I think the line affecting this is ``auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumera, consumerb)`` and ``auth.set_access_token(accessa, accessb)``.

Comment: If you are getting "KeyError" then the error is there, the variables are not loading ok. When you use get() Python does not give any error since if the key does not exist it returns None.
Print this "os.environ" to see a list of all the environment variables and check if yours are in.

Comment: Checked, nothing about all of my previously set ones are there, which I assume that my previously set ones weren't loading normally. Also, for your information, I set variables before running this script like ``TWICK=xxxx``. Is that right?

Comment: if you are in windows you have to do `set TWICK=xxxx` or setx (to do it permanently, set is for sesion). If you are in linux use `export TWICK=xxx`

Another workaround is to use a config file where you define your variables. There are libraries to load this type of files.

Comment: The variable method (``export TWICK=xxx``) should be working in this case. Thanks!